# What is difference between "community forks" and "personal-use forks" in github?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I want to answer to this question: How can community forks be distinguished from personal-use fork in any VCS . first i should Know that:

what is difference between **"community forks"** and **"personal-use forks"** in github?

Comment: Where did you find those terms?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh  Mining Software Repository challenge 2020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about "[MSR 2020 MC: MSR 2020 Mining Challenge](https://easychair.org/cfp/msr2020mc)"

> Cross-repository analysis: How can forking and duplication patterns inform us on software health and risks?
>   How can community forks be distinguished from personal-use forks? What are good predictors of the success of a community fork?

You can see an example of a community fork in [`getferdi/ferdi`](https://github.com/getferdi/ferdi): a duplication of another repository, now maintained by a [large community](https://github.com/getferdi/ferdi/graphs/contributors) (<del>53 contributors</del>, no, wait... [75 contributors in mid-2020](https://twitter.com/getferdi/status/1263370830169485312))

Those are not actual [GitHub forks](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).
They copy another repo and modify it without any intention of contributing back through pull request.
Another example: [`fomantic/Fomantic-UI`](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI), which duplicates [`Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI).

> Fomantic was created to continue active development of Semantic-UI and has the intent to be merged back into the master repository once active development can restart.

A personal-use fork is a classic [GitHub fork](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo), forked by one individual.

Comment: I wonder what those terms distinguishment trying to tell, sir?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh They are distinguishing between actual fork (duplication and independent history) and GitHub fork (with contribution back to the original repository)